# Auto size all columns to fit content in pivot ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I want to auto-size all columns' width so that they can fit their content in ag-grid while having pivot mode enabled

```
    /** @type {import('ag-grid-community').GridOptions} */
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'country', rowGroup: true,width:50, enableRowGroup: true },
    { field: 'athlete' },
    { field: 'sport', pivot: true, enablePivot: true },
    { field: 'year', pivot: true, enablePivot: true },
    { field: 'date', pivot: true, enablePivot: true },
    { field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'silver', aggFunc: 'sum' },
    { field: 'bronze', aggFunc: 'sum' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    minWidth: 50,
    width:40,
    filter: true,
    resizable: true,
  },
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
   // minWidth: 70,
  },
  pivotMode: true,
};
function size(){
    //gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(false);

  // Auto-size all columns
gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns()


  // Re-enable pivot mode
  //gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(true);
}




// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

  fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => gridOptions.api.setRowData(data));
});
```

but autosizeallcolumnstofit only makes visible columns expand by default, not the column which is hidden with scroll help. can anyone help me resolve this?. Thanks in advance